# Start a method when thread ends

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am relatively new to threading, so I am unsure if I am going about this correctly.

In my current application, I have a multi-tabbed navigational form, some of which have buttons that lead to other forms, some of which have tables, and some of which have both. On one such, I have a button to add an entry, and a table showing all entries for that day pulled via stored procedure.

When I opened that second form as a dialog, it was easy to refresh the table by calling the method I had created... however, it ran slow like that. Instead, I started calling it as another thread, which runs incredibly fast, but I can't seem to find a way to call the method when the thread ends. I've searched for a while, and I've not found a working solution.

Here is the code:

```
public static void ThreadProcAddEntry()
    {
        Application.Run(new AddEntry());
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProcAddEntry));
        t.Name = "AddEntry";
        t.Start();           
    }
```

and

```
public void GetMyEntries(string username)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB2"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GetUserEntries", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                using (reader)
                {
                    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    table.Load(reader);
                    dgvMyEntry.DataSource = table;
                    dgvMyEntry.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                    dgvMyEntry.ReadOnly = true;
                    dgvMyEntry.AutoResizeColumns();
                    dgvMyEntry.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

How would you suggest I run the GetMyEntries Method when the thread ends, which occurs as soon as I click the Submit button on the AddEntryForm (which, after submitting to SQL, runs a dispose method)?

Comment: Use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) instead of a thread for this. It has a event called `RunWorkerCompleted` that does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Also you are making a few odd choices like `using(reader)` instead of `using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())`

Comment: Scott, thank you. I am still learning, and am not always the most effecient in coding. The using re-statement worked perfect as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using tasks, as follows:

```
await Task
    .Run(() => ThreadProcAddEntry())
    .ContinueWith(task => GetMyEntries(username));
```

This is more succinct and readable than using raw Threads or background workers.

`GetMyEntries` will be run as soon as `ThreadProcAddEntry` completes.

More on the Task Parallel Library (async/await): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use, another wrapper method/interface provided by .NET framework. That is BackgroundWorker. For more information check msnd [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

// define the event handlers
backgroundWorker.DoWork += (sender, args) => {
    // do your lengthy stuff here -- this will happen in a separate thread
    ...
}
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => {
    if (args.Error != null)  // if an exception occurred during DoWork,
        MessageBox.Show(args.Error.ToString());  // do your error handling here

    // Do whatever else you want to do after the work completed.
    // This happens in the main UI thread.
    ...
}

backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); // starts the background worker
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a task

```
var task = Task.Run(() => ThreadProcAddEntry());

task.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() => GetMyEntries(username));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to simply call `GetMyEntries()` after `Application.Run(new AddEntry());` ?

If it is not in scope, then I'm afraid we need more detail of your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a raw Thread, you could use one of the helpful thread-wrapping classes .net provides. Specifically, this sounds like a perfect job for a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). You would create a new BackgroundWorker, add the code you want to run in the thread to the BackgroundWorker's DoWork event, add GetMyEntries to the BackgroundWorker's RunWorkerCompleted event, then call RunWorkerAsync().